# How to remove all occurences of a substring within a string except the first one visual basic

Tags: vb.net, substring

The code so far looks like this

```
    For i = 0 To (Len(needed) - 1)
        If key.Contains(needed(i)) = False Then
            key = key + needed(i)
        Else

        End If
```

Within the else I would want to remove all occurrences of the substring key(i) from key except the first one. I could do this using a flag variable within a for loop to gain the location of this and simply replace that with "" however I have the entire alphabet and 3 other characters to check for. Is there a better method to do this???

Comment: Hint: if IndexOf > 0 andalso IndexOf = LastIndexOf ...then stop replacing ...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to replace any occurrence of a string except the first one, you could get a substring representing the the string after the first one, and run the replace then.

```
key.Substring(key.IndexOf(key(i)) + 1).Replace(key(i), "")
```

Hope this helps.